# Google OAuth 2.0 SignIn API asks for contacts permission

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I have created a new Google account along with OAuth 2.0 credentials for Google sign in.

When Google asks the user for permission, it asks for "manage your contacts”.

Why am I getting this "manage your contacts”? I just wanted to do a Google sign in.

Answer (score 4):

When authenticating a user you are asking them for permission to access their data.

[image]

There is a large number of scopes for accessing google data scopes define what access you need and what access is requested of the user [huge list of scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

If you are seeing `manage your contacts` then you are probably requesting the following scope from the [people api](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#peoplev1).   If you dont want access to the users contacts then remove that scope and it will stop requesting it.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my application code scope was https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/. So I removed and it works.

Comment: If you're happy with this answer, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the contacts scopes you pass in to GoogleSignIn:

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  // scopes: <String>[
  //   //'email',
  //   //'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  // ],
);
```

This will stop asking for Contacts permission.

Scopes:

email- View your email address

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly -See and download your contacts

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts - See, edit, download, and permanently delete your contacts

Even if you remove the email scope, you will still be able to see the user's email by using GoogleSignInAccount account.email.

For more information on scopes:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes